# Oracle select across a group of tables by partial name

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to select information from a group of tables. Originally, I had

```
 SELECT table_name,
                    to_number(
                    extractvalue(
                    xmltype(
                    dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c '|| ' from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name))
                    ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
                    from all_tables
                    where table_name like 'PAY0%' OR  table_name like 'PAY1%'
```

Then looped through all the tables in my code using

```
 foreach(table_name in tables){
    SELECT CUST_NUMBER 
    FROM #table_name#
}
```

Now I'm trying to combine the two by doing the following in order to get the cust_number from every table, but it's saying '"CUST_NUMBER": invalid identifier'

```
select CUST_NUMBER 
                    from  ( SELECT table_name,
                            to_number(
                            extractvalue(
                            xmltype(
                            dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c '|| ' from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name))
                            ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
                            from all_tables
                            where table_name like 'PAY0%' OR  table_name like 'PAY1%') PayTables
```

I know the problem is the first query gets table names and not the data, but I've no idea how to get the data as well without looping through them seperately.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a PLSQL or plain SQL ?

Comment: Plain sql.  The loop was meant to just be pseudocode to show what I'm doing now. Only because I don't know PLSQL, maybe that is what I should be using? The important thing is I just need one result set of all tables named PAY01% or PAY02%

Comment: Yes it is. You definitely need to use plsql since dynamic sql can only be achieved through `execute immediate`  command. Right now I'm without time to elaborate an answer. If no one answer you I will later tonight (my local time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your need, something like the following could help:

```
declare
    vSQL varchar2(32767);
    type tabNum is table of number;
    vResult tabNum;
begin
    select listagg( 'select cust_number from ' || owner || '.' || table_name,
                    ' UNION ALL '
                  ) within group ( order by null)
    into vSQL
    from dba_tables
    where table_name like 'PAY0%' OR  table_name like 'PAY1%';    
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(vSQL);
    --
    execute immediate vSQL bulk collect into vResult;
    --    
    for i in vResult.first .. vResult.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(vResult(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

It dynamically builds an SQL statement that extracts values from all the tables matching you criteria; in the example I run the statement fetching the result into a structure, but you can open a cursor, or do whatever you need.